# Gem asset files when using Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

The asset files for a couple of gems I'm using aren't loading after using Nginx in production mode. I'm pretty certain it has to do with the location blocks in my Nginx config, but I'm not sure what to add so that Nginx will point to where the files are located.

The gems in question are sidekiq and rack-mini-profiler

```
upstream cable {
  server unix:///tmp/cable.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 66.207.0.133;
  root /home/john/rails/cable/public/assets;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://cable;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ~* \.(css|js|otf|woff|ttf|svg|eot)$ {
    root /home/john/rails/cable/public/;
  }

}
```

The error in the Nginx log is:

```
2016/11/07 21:04:36 [error] 22745#22745: *51175 open() "/home/john/rails/cable/public/sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 69.49.80.136, server: 66.207.0.133, request: "GET /sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js HTTP/1.1", host: "66.207.0.133", referrer: "http://66.207.0.133/sidekiq"
```

Obviously the second location block is redirecting all requests for the needed .js and .css files to the wrong location, but how and to where can I redirect requests to /sidekiq/*.js to the correct files?

Comment: Do you know where your gem asset files are located?

Comment: And the right location would be ...?

Comment: Thanks for accept/+1/bounty, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to [`find`](http://mdoc.su/n/find.1) where the correct files are in your filesystem.

```
find / -path "*/javascripts/dashboard.js"
```

A web search reveals that it might be `/home/site/homepage_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.16.1/web/assets/javascripts/dashboard.js`.

So, if you gotta serve that from `/sidekiq/javascripts/dashboard.js` on the web, and provided that all requests within `/sidekiq/` are for static assets, then the following should be used:

```
location ^~ /sidekiq/ {
    alias /home/site/homepage_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.16.1/web/assets/;
}
```

For more details, see:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/alias

Comment: Wouldn't that break as soon as you update the sidekiq to a slightly higher version?